# How can I customize the Quickinsert panel in Trados Studio 2015?

Tags: user-interface, xliff

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this - let me know if I need to migrate it.

[image]

I am trying to edit the "QuickInsert" panel in Trados Studio 2015. I couldn't find appropriate documentation online ([this](http://producthelp.sdl.com/SDL%20Trados%20Studio/client_en/Setting_Preferences/SpecifyKSs.htm) didn't help much), and at the moment I have to copy and paste every single special character...

Answer (score 0):

QuickInsert settings are file type specific. You can navigate to the file type definition of the file that you are working on and add what you need. I have selected the settings node for HTML 4 in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im6Q0.png).

You can find the official documentation of this feature [here](http://producthelp.sdl.com/SDL_Trados_Studio_2015/client_en/FileTypes/Customize_QuickInsert_Text_SpecialChars.html).